# Is a dense subspace of a separable topological space also separable?

Tags: general-topology

Question is said in title.Suppose X is a  separable topological space and S is a dense subspace of X,to prove S is separable or give a counter-example,and we may add what conditions to make this statement true?

Comment: What is a divisible topological space?

Comment: @LuizCordeiro sorry,it's separable,i've got it wrong

Comment: You can add the condition that $S$ is countable :)

Comment: @LuizCordeiro but X\{a} is not dense in X here

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892041/is-every-dense-subspace-of-a-separable-space-separable

Comment: @LuizCordeiro why in the first counter-example the sigma product is dense in pi product

Comment: This is from the definition of the product topology: If $(x_i)\in\prod_I[0,1]$, a basic open neighbourhood of $(x_i)$ has the form $\left\{(y_i):\operatorname{max}_{i\in F}|x_i-y_i|<\epsilon\right\}$, where $F\subseteq I$ is finite and $\epsilon>0$. Then setting $y_i=x_i$ for $i\in F$ and $0$ otherwise, we have $(y_i)$ in this neighbourhood.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro thanks!